# What is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} 3^{k^2}x^{k^2}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Where I'm at right now:

$a_k = 3^{k^2}$, so we do $\frac{1}{\lim sup_{k\to\infty}(3^{k^2})^{\frac{1}{k}}}$, which is $\frac{1}{3^k}$, but that doesn't seem right. I suppose from there, I go through the $\sup$, and when I think about it like that, I suppose the $sup_{k\to\infty}3^k$ is $3$, so the Radius of Convergence is $\frac{1}{3}$?

I'm not sure if that is the right way to the approach the problem though.

Comment: Several *lacunary* series such as this one have been asked on the site previously. The simplest approach is to consider these as series $\sum a_n$ with general term $a_n=3^{n^2}x^{n^2}$ and to determine when $a_n\to0$. If $a_n\to0$, a simple argument then shows that the series converges hence one is done.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134949/find-the-interval-of-convergence-for-these-3-power-series/1134969#1134969).

Comment: The reason your calculation is giving the wrong answer is that you are using $a_k = 3^{k^2}$ when really you should be doing $a_k = 0$ if $k$ is not a perfect square, $a_k = 3^k$ if $k$ is a perfect square.

Answer (score 1):

The series does have the radius of convergence of $1/3$. Here is another way of looking at it:

Notice that the series $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k^2}$ converges when $|x| < 1$ (for instance you can compare it to a geometric series for positive $x$ and use the alternating series test for negative $x$) and diverges when $x=1$. This means that the radius of convergence is 1. Consequently, $f(3x)$, which gives your series, must converge when $|3x|<1$ or when $|x|<1/3$.

Answer (score 0):

That's just

$$\sum_{\text{occasional j}} (3x)^j$$
and that "sup" in $\limsup$ ensures that missing terms don't do much, because you are looking at the biggest terms, which are the same as for the geometric series. Therefore, the result is $1/3$.

Comment: How does $3^{k^2}$ becomes $(3x)^j$?

Comment: $j=k^2$ and group the terms. The sum only goes over perfect squares now.